# XCode Version 7.1 (7B91b) and TFS 2013 GIT Authentication Failure

Tags: xcode, git, tfs, xcode7.1

We are working on Xcode Project connected to our local TFS 2013 (Update 3) Server via TFS Provided Git Repository.

When we use older version of Xcode, we are successfully able to check-in the files and perform all other Git operations. We are also able to perform all Git  Operations via command line Git.

The trouble is when we use latest version of Xcode - Version 7.1 (7B91b).
On entering valid credentials, we are getting error saying

`Authentication failed because the user name or password was incorrect.`

The same credentials / configuration work on older version of Xcode and Git Command Line Options.

To add more to the surprises, we are able to connect to github.com successfully.

We are able to reproduce issue on other systems too. Please provide us the best way to resolve this error.

Comment: You can connect to github.com successfully doesn't mean that you can connect to TFS repository as well, because they are different source control system. Can you use the same credential to connect to TFS directly?

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT - Am able to connect to TFS directly from Browser as well as through Command Line GIT. Am also able to connect successfully from older version of XCode - 6.x series. It simply does not work with latest version of XCode - 7.1

Comment: TFS 2012 doesn't have Git Repos.

Comment: @DaveShaw - Just edited - it's for TFS 2013 Update 3.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. cannot authenticate in XCode to connect to TFS Git repository.

Comment: We have the same issue with TFS 2015. Older xCode Versions are working, git consol is working but not xCode 7.1. ??? Our Workaround is using the git consol...

Comment: Same issue with Xcode 7.3.1, TFS 2015 Update 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For us it turned out to be because Xcode 7 does not support Windows Authentication. The solution described here solved it for us:

> "This happens because XCode 7 doesn't support Windows Authentication.
>   I don't know why. It seems to be a common problem amongst users
>   because there are many posts about it in google.
>
> To make it all work you should enable Basic Authentication in your IIS
>   TFS website on "tfs" virtual folder.
>
> Be careful though because basic authentication sends your credentials
>   over network as plain text. You definitely must use SSL in this case."

([source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4519b491-b42e-4f6e-b59c-42a8e4be2ea0/local-tfs-2015-authentication-error-using-git-on-xcode-cant-log-in?forum=tee))